# Glow Effect to <a> tag when selected

Tags: css

I am currently in the process of adding a navigation bar to a test site. I have seen some navigation bar indicate the current selected page by adding a bar underneath or glow to the `<a>` tag. I am right now puzzled in the right way to achieve such css style. How can i achieve a glow effect around a selected `<a>` so the user will now the page they currently at?  [EXAMPLE](http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/index.php)

Thank you

For my `<a>` tags i have created a `.buttonNav` class

**CSS related rules for navigation bar:**

```
<style>
/**************  Header Styling ****************/
#navigation {
    left: 440px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: relative;
}


#contentNav { color: #cfdae3; }
/* Dark Button CSS */
.buttonNav {
    outline: 0;
    padding: 5px 12px;
    display: block;
    color: #EBEBEB;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #1f272b;
    border: 1px solid #1c252b;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #232B30;
}
.buttonNav:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: #4C5A64; 
}
.buttonNav:active {
    background-position: 0 top;
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px 12px 4px;
    background: #20282D; 
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.1); /* CSS3 */
}
.button-list {
    list-style: none outside none;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.button-list li { float: left; margin: 0 5px 0 0; }
.button-list li.search { padding-left: 18px; margin-left: 10px; position: relative; list-style: none outside none;}

</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="search"><input type="text" class="search-input" name="search" value="Search" onclick="$(this).val('');" /><input type="submit" class="search-submit" /></div>
  <div id="navigation">

   <ul class="button-list">
       <h2>MAIN TITLE PAGE</h2>
    <li><a href="http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/index.php" class="buttonNav" >Content 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://webprolearner2346.zxq.net/css-test2/content2.php" class="buttonNav" >Content 2</a></li> 
   </ul> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would put in some jquery to handle this automatically something like

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      var str = location.href.toLowerCase();
      $(".navigation li a").each(function () {
          if (str.indexOf(this.href.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
              $("li.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
              $(this).parent().addClass("highlight");
          }
      });
  })
```

This function will add a css class `highlight` to the active `li` `a` element. **IF and only if**  the name of the next page is the same as the text. So if the link is called "Product.html" you'll want the text of the `a` element to be "Product"

the an example of the HTML

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li class="highlight"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="product.html">Product</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

the css would change the background color slightly.

```
.highlight{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

you know or put in the glow effect you want

hope this helps,

EDIT: working tutorial/demo http://blog.huidesign.com/automatically-highlight-current-page-in-navigation-with-css-jquery/

EDIT2: thanks to Sven Bieder, for helping better understand.

Comment: +1 Thank you. This method seems like the best. But i tried and nothing is happening.

Comment: Make sure you have jquery added in your header. you can learn more about it here: http://jquery.com/

Comment: -1 This method has absolutely no sense. For what should I use jQuery to change a class and then redirect to another page. Then my changed class is lost again.

Comment: @SvenBieder You have a point here sir, what would you recommend sir?

Comment: please look at this demo: http://blog.huidesign.com/wp-content/demo/highlight_navigation/index.html then look at the Jquery http://blog.huidesign.com/automatically-highlight-current-page-in-navigation-with-css-jquery/ .. it does infact work

Comment: I recommend Jake Long's answer for a structure like yours. Changing the class with jQuery makes only sense in a one page enviroment.

Comment: @Eric What you are trying to defend here is absolutely wrong. You should read that tutorial at first yourself very carefully. In that tutorial is a string comparison and that works only out when you have the file-name of your pages the same like the link-text

Comment: Okay you have a point there, I'll alter my original answer to work. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

if you add a class

```
.currentPage {
  background: #yourDifferentColor;
  (box-shadow)..
  (text-decoration)..
}
```

and add it to the link that represents the current page (you will have to do this on all pages), you can define the style of the current page's link to be different from the others, to your spec.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you usually take care of this on server-level. Right now it's pretty easy.
If you are on the index page, simply go the the link pointing to the index page in your navigation and add a class or inline style to it.